# Is it possible to generate react props using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to generate a prop for each of the paragraph created.

```
  var TabContent = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
     var paragraph = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < this.props.nrPar; i++) {
          var x = "p" + i; //or can I use a variable after this.props.?
          paragraph.push(<p key={i}>{this.props.p + i}<br></br></p>);
     }

     return(              

        <div>            
              {paragraph}
        </div>
       );
   }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(

     <TabContent nrPar="3" 
      p1="first paragraph of text" 
      p2="second paragraph of text" 
      p3="third paragraph of text"/>

      ,month
  )
```

I want to be able to choose the amount of paragraphs I want to create and be able to write text in each of them.

**nrPar** is the number of paragraphs that I want to be created.

**p1, p2, p3** are the result of **nrPar** because I want 3 paragraphs for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ReactJs` you can pass arrays as props. Modified your code little bit.

```js
var TabContent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var paragraph = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.paragraphs; i++) {
      paragraph.push(<p key={i}>{this.props.paragraphs[i]}<br></br></p>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {paragraph}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <TabContent
    paragraphs={[
      `first paragraph of text`,
      `second paragraph of text`
    ]}
  />
  , month
)
```

Comment: Awesome!! Better than what I was thinking!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a bit of an antipattern to me. The easiest way would probably be just to pass an array of strings as a prop.

If you need to do something with the paragraph count, just get the array length like so:

```js
const TabContent = props => (
  <div>
    <p>count: {props.paragraphs.length}</p>
    {props.paragraphs.map((paragraph, index) => (
      <p key={index}>{paragraph}</p>
    ))}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <TabContent paragraphs={["first", "second"]} />,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: your code is different than mine... I'm new to react and I learned from a book where the code was different than they way you coded the answer above. I'm not sure how to add that to my entire code. Should I change the way I code react and code as you do? I've seen a lot of people coding that way.. I'm still new to this!

Comment: `React.createClass` was deprecated in React 15.5 (April 2017), so less people are using it nowadays. This is basically the same thing, just with different syntax.

Comment: Things change fast in the JS world, sometimes way too fast… The book you have was likely written before that happened. This article might shed a bit more light on it: https://medium.com/@npverni/how-to-declare-react-components-in-2017-2a90d9f7984c